# Getting a sum into a Table from another table based on a field value

Tags: ms-access

And I'm looking at whether it's possible to have a table which is used to record a daily output? The daily output would be recorded under an ID (as there are several IDs).

Therefore, I have two tables, one is the list of IDs which have the field for IDs & total output, and another table that records the daily output which contains the fields for IDs, Daily Output, & Output Date.

Therefore I want to put the sum of recorded Daily Output by respective ID into the ID List table.

Answer (score 0):

To create this answer, I used the following structure:

```
tblDailyOutput - table name  
   (Key field is combination of ID and Output_Date)  
ID - number field  
Output_Date - date field  
Daily_Output - number field holding the daily totals  

tblOutputTotal - table name  
ID - number field, key field  
TotalOutput - number field
```

I would do this in two steps:

1. Delete the records in Output_Total. By deleting the records you do not have to add new IDs and update existing IDs, but all of the IDs will be there every time.

Query:

```
DELETE tblOutputTotal.* FROM tblOutputTotal;
```

2. Create an append query to Output_Total that adds the totals to your Output_Total table.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO tblOutputTotal ( ID, TotalOutput )
    SELECT tblDailyOutput.ID, Sum(tblDailyOutput.Daily_Output) AS SumOfDaily_Output
    FROM tblDailyOutput
    GROUP BY tblDailyOutput.ID;
```